# Apple reject my app with error Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, app-store

This is error message:
Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue because we need additional

[image]

I don't know why and how to fix it. Any body can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We need more information. Also, you can check your email for more details about the rejection.

Comment: Please check https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808528-iOS-Troubleshooting-Metadata-Rejected-in-App-Store-Review-Status

Comment: The information/message is hidden on the right side of the page due to bad web design from Apple's end. Try to maximize the window and/or view it on a bigger screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read all the information shared by Apple . You will get the exact cause of "Rejection"

Answer (score 2):

[**2.1 App Completeness**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness)

Submissions to App Review should be final versions with all necessary metadata and fully functional URLs included; placeholder text, empty websites, and other temporary content should be scrubbed before submission. Make sure your app has been tested on-device for bugs and stability before you submit it, ***and include demo account info (and turn on your back-end service!) if your app includes a login***. If you offer in-app purchases in your app, make sure they are complete, up-to-date, and visible to the reviewer, or that you explain why not in your review notes. Please don’t treat App Review as a software testing service. We will reject incomplete app bundles and binaries that crash or exhibit obvious technical problems.